# Executing nodejs binaries on NTFS partition ends with Permission failure

Tags: 14.04, permissions, ntfs, partitioning, nodejs

```
npm run <module-name>
npm start <module-name>
npm * <module-name>
```

Running locally installed modules with npm ends with :

```
sh: 1: <module-name>: Permission denied
```

So I've been dealing with that issue for hours trying `chown` commands with no success and finally I researched that it has to do with my partition is NTFS that I am sharing with a secondary windows OS.

What might be done so that ubuntu doesn't threat the partition that way?

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

- Find the directory of your mounted partition:

Usually `/media/<your_username>/<the_partition_name>`
Let's assume your username is `moo` and the partition name is `mystuff` the mount path would be `/media/moo/mystuff`.

- Unmount the partition with the unmount button next to it
- Create a folder with the same path as the partion:

  `sudo mkdir /media/<your_username>/<the_partition_name>`
- Then mount the partition to it:

  `sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,defaults,exec /dev/disk/by-label/<the_partition_name> /media/<your_username>/<the_partition_name>`

thus preserving any path references you have to it.

- After you finish you can unmount the partition manually again in which case the folder you've created is left empty
- Delete the folder so that you can mount the usual way to the same path without executive permissions as you did so far:

  `sudo rmdir /media/<your_username>/<the_partition_name>`

I found this method to work for me because:

- I need these kind of permissions occasionally
- It preserves my outside path references to the partition
- I have the free option of mounting the default way

If you need permission access to be your default you should consider defaulting these settings.